# Get Unhandled exception at 0x00f85069

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

my program breaks and says this

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00f85069 in Monopoly.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000c.
```

i made a win32 wrapper. i have two WndProc one is static and the other one not. the static WndProc calls the nonstatic WndProc.  when i try to get messages it works fine but when i try to set a value for something it throw a exception.
here is my code for two WndProc(the first one its that static)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Window::StaticWndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) 
{ 
   if ( msg == WM_CREATE ) 
   { 
       SetWindowLongPtr( hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG)((CREATESTRUCT *)lParam)->lpCreateParams ); 
   }
   Window *targetApp = (Window*)GetWindowLongPtr( hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA );

   return targetApp->WndProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam ); 
}

LRESULT CALLBACK Window::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        z=-14; //IT THROW EXCEPTION
        break;
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
        z-=1;
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT:**
VARABILES
int z;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you creating your window? Did you pass a valid pointer to an instance of `Window` to your `CreateWindow()` or `CreateWindowEx()` function via the `lpParam` parameter? For example, if your window wrapper has a `Create()` function or something like that:

```
void Window::Create()
{
    /* ... */

    // Pass a pointer to ourselves to CreateWindow() via the lpParam parameter.
    // CreateWindow() then passes that pointer to your window procedure
    // (StaticWndProc) via WM_CREATE and WM_NCCREATE in the lpCreateParams member
    // of CREATESTRUCT. This way the window procedure will know which instance to
    // call WndProc() on.
    CreateWindow(lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y, nWidth, nHeight,
        hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, (LPVOID)this);

    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, an access violation (`0xC0000005`) means you accessed memory that you shouldn't have. In this case it says you were trying to write to `0x0000000c`. Since you (your debugger?) say that the assignment to `z` causes it, may we see the definition of that symbol, please? Also, is it really `z = -14` or `z -= 14`?

Edit: I think you need to replace `((CREATESTRUCT *)lParam)->lpCreateParams` with a valid pointer to an instance of `class Window`.

Edit #2: What happens is this: On `WM_CREATE`, you set `GWLP_USERDATA` to a value that happens to be equal to `NULL`. Subsequently, you read that value and treat it as a valid pointer to a `Window` by invoking a non-static member function on that pointer. Class member functions are *implemented* by the compiler a lot like so

```
LRESULT CALLBACK <mangled_name ("Window::WndProc")> (Window * const this, HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    // ...
}
```

That is the reason that you can actually invoke a member function on a `NULL` pointer. However, once you access a member variable, like `z`, this breaks. The compiler inserted code similar to this `*((int*) (this + 0xc)) = -14`, (which BTW means that `z` lies 0xc bytes into your `Window` instance), which, since `this == NULL`, broke.

Comment: z=-14 im just testing my wrapper

Comment: I think you need to replace `((CREATESTRUCT *)lParam)->lpCreateParams` with a valid pointer to an instance of `class Window`.

Answer (score 1):

The object on which you're calling `WndProc` seems to be non-existent (null?) and you have an access violation upon trying to write the memory in `z -= 14` which is `this->z -= 14` (`this` being an invalid pointer). That's my guess.

Also, Access Violation is not not an exception in C++ terms. :)